# UUID as primary key not working Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, uuid

**We've using UUID as primary key in laravel, I've created a record and its working but I've unable to get this record with UUID.**

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL ,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
) ;
```

Laravel  code:

Model:

```
class User extends Model {
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated';
    protected $table = 'user';
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    protected $incremental = false;
}
```

Controller:

```
$contact = User::find(hex2bin('11E7094BFDB648529F5F7429AF41FD58'));
```

But result is always Null. :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make uuid field in laravel there are two way inside schema model

```
$table->uuid('uuid')->unique();
```

or

```
$table->char('uuid', 36)->unique();
```

and make sure add the fillable

```
protected $fillable = [ 'uuid', 'name'];
```

Also You can take a look at this package

https://github.com/EmadAdly/laravel-uuid

by easy way can (create, add, search uuid) generate UUID and inject it inside uuid field automatically for any model when adding a new row, also you can search by uuid easily.